# Avoiding For Loops / Iterating over two tables

Tags: python, pandas

I have two large pandas dataframes and am currently using nested for loops to perform the calculation listed below. This is highly inefficient and takes forever to run. I was wondering if anyone has an approach other than iterables / for loops to perform the following calc:

1. I have two dataframes:

**source**

[image]

and **destination**:

[image]

I want to join the data from source and destination to get the following **output**:

[image]

The rules that I apply:

1. The total of amt (38) in the source table remains the same in the output table
2. There can be multiple columns present in source ( like Business) not present in destination.
3. The logic starts at the beginning of the source table and proceeds to the end.
4. Cells in green have a perfect match ( ie instrument and entity ) between source and destination tables. The Depot column is the new column in the output
   5.Cells in Yellow have a lower Amt in the source, the Source Amt is maintained in the output
5. Cells in Orange have no match in the destination, so the Amt is shown without a depot
6. Cells in blue have a lower match in the destination so are split up

I am able to achieve the logic above using a nested for loop. However, this is not efficient and was wondering if there is a Pythonic approach to achieve this more efficiently.

Comment: Please provide sample data in text instead of picture.

Comment: Sounds like a merge.

Comment: Ive tried to merge the two data sets in vain !

Answer (score 1):

import pandas as pd

destination.drop(['Instrument', 'Amt'], axis = 1, inplace = True) 
source = pd.merge(source, destination, on = 'Entity', how = 'left')